# Trying to join multiple tables. Two tables is not directly related. Linq query fails

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

I have problem with LINQ query, when i trying to join multiple tables. Two of which is not directly related.
I need to get all reports about screens binded to a specific Venue (VenueId in Display).

```
We have 3 classes:
public class Report
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("ReportId")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public Guid FromUuid { get; set; }
        public int FromMajor { get; set; }
        public int FromMinor { get; set; }

        …

    }

public class Screen
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("DisplayId")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Id")]
        public Display Base { get; set; }

        public string Uuid { get; set; }
        public int Major { get; set; }
        public int Minor { get; set; }

    }

public class Display
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("DisplayId")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DisplayType Type { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int VenueId {get; set}

         …
    }
```

So I wrote Linq request:

```
var result =
               from r in db.Reports
               join fs in db.Screens on new { a = r.FromUuid.ToString(), b = r.FromMajor, c = r.FromMinor } equals new { a = fs.Uuid, b = fs.Major, c = fs.Minor }
               join display in db.Displays on fs.Id equals display.Id
               where fs.Base.VenueId == VenueId
                select new { Uuid = r.FromUuid, Major = r.FromMajor, Minor = r.FromMinor, StartTime = r.StartTime};

            var bla = await result.ToListAsync();
```

And i got this fail:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidCastException: Kan ikke bruke objekttypen Sys-tem.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer,<>f__AnonymousType5`3[System.String,System.Int32,System.Int32]]] som Sys-tem.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression.
```

I wrote also raw sql , just to testing and it works

```
var test =  db.Reports.FromSql("SELECT 
c.FromUuid as FromUuid, c.FromMajor as FromMajor, c.FromMinor as FromMinor, " +
                 "FROM Reports AS c " +
                "LEFT JOIN screens AS b ON c.FromUuid = b.Uuid AND c.FromMajor = b.Major AND c.FromMinor = b.Minor " +
                "LEFT JOIN displays AS d ON d.DisplayId = b.DisplayId " +

               "WHERE d.VenueId = 2010")
                .ToList();
```

But we want to use Linq.

What is wrong with Linq request?

Comment: Not 100% on this, but aren't you trying to perform an equality check on two anonymous types?  Does it work if you join on each individual property?

Comment: Actually it works when i removed join display. So looks like that the problem is with joining display table. This Linq query works:
              from calDist in db.CalibratedDistances
               join frombc in db.Beacons on new { a = calDist.FromUuid.ToString(), b = calDist.FromMajor, c = calDist.FromMinor } equals new { a = frombc.Uuid, b = frombc.Major, c = frombc.Minor }
               //join display in db.Displays on frombc.Id equals display.Id

Comment: You are trying to compare an integer displayID against a Display : public Display Base { get; set; }

Comment: sorry, where i doing this? here:   on fs.Id equals display.Id 
 ? But how it must be?

Comment: Looking at the exception you're getting I'd guess that: `r.FromUuid.ToString()`  is your issue.  `new { a = r.FromUuid.ToString(), b = r.FromMajor, c = r.FromMinor } ` is an Expression that gets converted to sql.  So internally the conversion process does not know how to convert a Guid to string in sql and throws an exception.

Comment: In your SQL you are comparing the `Guid` type to `string` directly - what is the actual column types in the table? `c.FromUuid = b.Uuid` Why are the two columns different C# types?

Comment: In table Screens, Uuid was NVARCHAR and in table Report fromUid was uniqueidentifier.  It was the problem. I changed Screen Uuid property type to Guid and Linq query works. So, problem is solved. Thanks for help!